# What commands are used to show the date/time and calendar in a dialog box of a system in linux?

Tags: linux

I would like to use mobaXterm term to show the date/time and calendar in a system dialog box. I've tried this command for the date and time:

```
dialog --title "System date and time" --infobox "Date is 'date'"
```

For the calendar I tried:

```
dialog  --title "Calender" --infobox "'cat nenuchoice.temp.$$'" 10 12
```

Comment: You've misspelled "Calendar" (several times), and I suspect that "nenuchoice.temp.$$" should actually be "menuchoice.temp.$$". You should proofread your commands.

Comment: A good idea also is to get the command actual output, as the first command misses the infobox dimensions, which are mandatory.  But the problem is in the single quotes, that seem to be used incorrectly.  You need to use backquotes, not single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Just use back ticks to delimit the date command, not normal apostrophos/single quotes, or use the bash specific alternative syntax `$(date)` as in

```
dialog --title "System date and time" --infobox "Date is `date`" 8 50

dialog --title "Calender" --infobox "`cat nenuchoice.temp.$$`" 10 12
```

or

```
dialog --title "System date and time" --infobox "Date is $(date)" 8 50

dialog --title "Calender" --infobox "$(cat nenuchoice.temp.$$)" 10 12
```